# Flash CC html5 canvas playback animation

Tags: javascript, html, flash, animation, canvas

I'm trying to make a playback animation with flash cc and html5 canvas

So when I use something like

```
this.gotoAndPlay(200);
```

works great in forward linear animation scenario, but what if I want to go from frame 200 to frame 0, playback the animation, or play the animation backwards, is this possible?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is one simple example:

```
var maxframe = 104
this.gotoAndStop(maxframe)

this.addEventListener('tick', playReverse.bind(this));


function playReverse()
{
        maxframe--;
        this.gotoAndStop(maxframe)
}
```

This will go to frame 104 and then go back to frame 0. Of course frame number check should be added, etc ... but you get the idea.